# How to use datatables with html and angularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm trying to use jquery datatables in html and angularjs. here i tried to write code but when i search anything shows no record found, even i try to sort data it also shows no record found.. even there is a lot of data..
here is what i wrote..

```
<table class="table table-striped" datatable="ng" id="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Job Title</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>No Of Positions</th>
              <th>Job Positions</th>
              <th>Job Time</th>
              <th>Experience</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="pendingJobs in pending">
              <td>{{pendingJobs.id}}</td>
              <td>{{pendingJobs.job_title}}</td>
              <td>{{pendingJobs.descr}}</td>
              <td>{{pendingJobs.no_positions}}</td>
              <td>{{pendingJobs.job_position}}</td>
              <td>{{pendingJobs.job_time}}</td>
              <td>{{pendingJobs.experience}}</td>
              <td><a href="#" title="Approve">
                <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true" title="Approve" ng-click="markAsApprove(pendingJobs.id);"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Edit"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete"></i>
              </a></td>
              <td><a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" title="View Detail"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" title="Edit"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete"></i>
              </a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is php json file..

```
 <?php
//database settings
include "../inc/db.php";
$query="select * from jobs where status = 'pending'";
//$data = array();
$rs=mysqli_query($db,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

    print json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: It would help if you include what angular-datatables library you use, and what `datatable="ng"` does

Comment: There is only HTML part of your code. You should access your database through Angulra, without this part of code none will be able to help you because probably there error is.

Comment: Also provide your `$scope.pending` JSON please.

Comment: there is no error in json file it's working fine without datatables